# How can I extract lines which their second column present in other file?

Tags: shell, awk

I have two files. 'Data file' is a csv file and the second one is 'item file' which in every line there is an item id. I want to extract lines of data which their second column is present in 'item file'.

For example:

- 23,18,4,2,2,2,1,2,1,2,1
- 26,17,5,4,1,3,1,1,2,2,1
- 26,18,4,4,1,3,1,2,2,2,1
- 26,16,1,3,1,3,1,1,2,2,1

and item list is:

- 18
- 20

Output: the first and third rows

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: asked and answered hundreds of times on this site alone. search the archives for 2 mins and you'll find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are GNU awk's solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} ARGIND==1{items[$1]=1} ARGIND==2 {if (items[$2]) print;}' "item file" "Data file"
```

`ARGIND` means the command line parameter number, here represents the file position.

And it can be simplified as:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=",";RS="\r?\n"} ARGIND==1{items[$1]=1} ARGIND==2 && items[$2]' "item file" "Data file"
```

Thanks @karakfa and @EdMorton for these improving points.

Comment: `{if(x) print}` can be written simply as `x`

Comment: @EdMorton  What's ITYM mean?

Comment: @EdMorton Got it, that's true. I did create the files for testing on windows. I worked a lot with gawk in batch files, so I do know these `bizarre quoting rules`. Nowadays I tended to open bash first and then test these...

Answer (score 2):

same logic can be written as

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next} $2 in a' itemlist FS=, data
```

Comment: @Tiw that;s the idiomatic solution that appears as the answer to hundreds of questions on this site alone, it needs no explanation.

Comment: @EdMorton  I don't like `NR==FNR` because when the first file is empty, it will process wrongly. I didn't realize that `ARGIND` is a GNU awk only feature.

Comment: Then use `FILENAME==ARGV[1]` for portability. That will fail if/when the same file is included twice on the command line though, e.g. for a 2-pass solution.

Comment: @EdMorton  Are there other ways to avoid these pitfalls? Thanks for the recommendation :)

Comment: Yes but it involves processing in the BEGIN section which includes separating file names from variable settings that may be present mixed in with the file names so it's not trivial or in some cases use of a `while getline` loop in the BEGIN section can be appropriate, see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Perl solution

```
/tmp> cat data.csv
23,18,4,2,2,2,1,2,1,2,1
26,17,5,4,1,3,1,1,2,2,1
26,18,4,4,1,3,1,2,2,2,1
26,16,1,3,1,3,1,1,2,2,1
/tmp> cat item.lst
18
20
/tmp> perl -lne ' $kv{$_}++ if $ARGV eq "item.lst"; /,(\S+?),/ and $kv{$1} and print ' item.lst data.csv
23,18,4,2,2,2,1,2,1,2,1
26,18,4,4,1,3,1,2,2,2,1
/tmp>
```

More readable format

```
/tmp> perl -lne ' if($ARGV eq "item.lst") { $kv{$_}++ }; if( $ARGV eq "data.csv") { print if /,(\S+?),/ and $kv{$1} } ' item.lst data.csv
23,18,4,2,2,2,1,2,1,2,1
26,18,4,4,1,3,1,2,2,2,1
/tmp>
```